# Failed to load data file into Azure blob storage container with Python program

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure storage account connection string to load a data file into Azure blob storage container, using Python program. Here is the code snippet of my program:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

... ...

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "test"

# Create the container
container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)

upload_file_path = "dummy_data.xlsx"

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=upload_file_path)

# Upload file
with open(file=upload_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

My program successfully created a container in the blog storage, but failed to load data into the container, with error message like this:

ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:adfasa-asdfa0adfa
Time:2022-10-25T20:32:19.0165690Z
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
authenticationerrordetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'bacadreRER=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

I got stuck with the error. I tried to use SAS key and it worked. Why it's not working for a connection string?  I am following Microsoft's code example to write my program:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli

Tried to manually upload data file with Azure Portal, and it worked. Using SAS key string in my Python code was also working. But it didn't work with Access Key connection string. It's odd that with the connection string I could create a container successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I executed the same code and successfully uploaded file in blob storage.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

connect_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage326123;AccountKey=3Lf7o2+vi3HgGKmUWaIG4xVdyzrzhxW5NxDNaUGVwykBPT5blZNKIyjbQlo0OAfuz0nllLUOGLRs+ASt9gqF+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "test"

# Create the container
container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)

upload_file_path = "C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Downloads\\dog.jpg"

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=upload_file_path)

# Upload file
with open(file=upload_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

> ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request.Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:adfasa-asdfa0adfa
> Time:2022-10-25T20:32:19.0165690ZErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
> authenticationerrordetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request'bacadreRER=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

The above error shows you missing something in connection string also check with signature.

You can get the connection string by

[image]